# How to remove border from embedded social media posts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, iframe

While I appreciate this question comes up every now and then, I have looked pretty much into every response I could without any luck so far. So, I decided to open a fresh thread...

I am trying to embed a LinkedIn post onto a webpage and no matter what I try regarding the border width and whatnot, there is always a light gray frame around the embedded post. The same border appears when embedding both Facebook posts and Tweets. My impression is that the original posts on these platforms all have light gray borders, so the embedded versions will have, too. I wonder if there is any workaround that does not involve rewriting the whole social media experience.

Thank you for your help. See sample code below.

```
<!-- YouTube iframe version below -->

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mhrkdHshb3E" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>


<!-- Twitter js version below -->

<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">More than 100 spacecraft have been signed up to fly on Falcon 9 since we launched the rideshare program. Small satellite operators can book their ride to orbit online → <a href="https://www.spacex.com/rideshare/index.html">https://www.spacex.com/rideshare/index.html</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/spaceflightinc/status/1273347941105795072">https://twitter.com/spaceflightinc/status/1273347941105795072</a></p>&mdash; SpaceX (@SpaceX) <a href="https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1273426202188005377?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">June 18, 2020</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<!-- facebook iframe version below -->

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FNASA%2Fphotos%2Fa.67899501771%2F10158346617536772%2F&show_text=true&width=552&height=458&appId" width="552" height="458" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>

<!-- facebook js version below -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v7.0" nonce="6zFKXsAI"></script>

<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/NASA/photos/a.67899501771/10158346617536772/" data-show-text="true" data-width=""><blockquote cite="https://developers.facebook.com/NASA/photos/a.67899501771/10158346617536772/?type=3" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><p>Astronomers are used to studying celestial objects that are millions or even billions of years old. That’s why a...</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/NASA/">NASA - National Aeronautics and Space Administration</a> on&nbsp;<a href="https://developers.facebook.com/NASA/photos/a.67899501771/10158346617536772/?type=3">Wednesday, June 17, 2020</a></blockquote></div> 


<!-- LinkedIn iframe version below -->

<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6674757258863222784" height="209" width="504" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" title="Embedded post"></iframe>
```

Comment: These social plugins either render as iframes with content loaded from a different origin, or as Shadow DOM components, meaning you have no access to their inside elements. At most you could try and cut off the border, by sticking them into a parent with hidden overflow, and give them a -1px margin on all sides, or something like that.

Comment: Really helpful, thanks, CBroe.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {position: relative; border: 2px solid #fff; width: 500px; height: 300px}
iframe {position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0}
p {margin: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; border: 2px solid #FFF; z-index: 2; box-sizing: border-box}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6674757258863222784" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" title="Embedded post">
  </iframe>
  <p></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be useful for you to explain your answer a bit.

Comment: Hello Төрболд Жаргал and thank you for your answer. Since I am a beginner, could you please confirm to me that your solution draws a white border on top of the existing light gray border from the original embedded post? If not, what is the mechanism used? Tks!

Comment: The data from LinkedIn had a grey border. It's unable for you to make it disappear with CSS or JS. So I used p and div tag with position property to produce white border over the iframe.